# Get static property through reflection .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've seen this answered already, but it hasn't worked for me. I'm trying to access a (non-static) class static property from the base class, from an derived instance.

In the base class:

```
Type type = this.GetType();
PropertyInfo propInf = type.GetProperty("DirectoryCode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Here propInf is null (type is the derived class type).

In the derived class:

```
public class DTGCSMissonParameters : ModelBase
{
   public static ushort DirectoryCode = (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS;
```

Thanks

Comment: The thing you defined is a **Field** not a **Property**, so you cannot find it as a property. For **C# 6.0**  _try: `public static ushort DirectoryCode {get; } = (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS;`_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Write it as an answer. Write: "Use `GetField` instead of `GetProperty`".

Comment: I see Bjarke already did. So I'll support his. _(I don't like adding similar answers)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JeroenVanLangen specified in the comments, you defined a Field instead of a Property. The correct statement should be:

```
// C# 6.0
public static ushort DirectoryCode => (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS;

// Pre-C# 6.0
public static ushort DirectoryCode
{ 
     get { return (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS; }
}
```

@Edit: As Jeppe Stig Nielsen pointed out in the comments, the first of the proposed solutions would be evaluated every time the property was accessed. To avoid this, and simply have it preserve the value in the property itself, use:

```
public static ushort DirectoryCode { get; } = (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS;
```

Comment: Or, if he wants the field as it is, use `GetField` instead of `GetProperty`.

Comment: Note: Your suggestions re-evaluate `DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS` every time the `get` accessor of the property is called. That is not what the field did. If you want to evaluate `DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS` only once, and early (at the time the static constructor for `DTGCSMissonParameters` runs), use `public static ushort DirectoryCode { get; } = (ushort) DIR.MISSION_PARAMETERS;` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Will be using GetField, as I am using VS2013 with C#5. Will try to get VS2015, for now it works.